# Comparator best practice when items cannot be logically compared

Tags: java, comparator

First of all this is an academic question, so let's not worry about whether the practice is good or not.
Let's say we have a `TreeSet<"Object">` and we want to instantiate it with a comparator. This comparator would return the usual 0, -1, and 1 but only if the two objects are the same class. So when the objects belong to different classes and it makes no sense to compare them, what should the comparator return? -1 or 1? Or does the contract for comparator mandate that I *have* to specify an order in all cases if I don't want to throw a runtime exception?

Answer (score 2):

A `Comparator` must specify an ordering between all the possible values it may receive. You cannot have two objects which may be part of your data structure the `Comparator` cannot "handle". If it makes no sense to compare them, just make an arbitrary decision. E.g., if they aren't of the same class, just compare the class names:

```
if (!a.getClass().equals(b.getClass()) {
    return a.getClass().getName().compare(b.getClass().getName());
}
```

Comment: So I guess the contract is that if I were to create a comparator I have to specify an order for all possible input if I don't want to throw an exception.

Comment: @FaiLau yup, and that ordering needs to be consistent. I.e., for every `a` and `b`, if `a.compareTo(b) < 0` it must imply that `b.compareTo(a) > 0` and if `a.compareTo(b) = 0`, it must imply that also `b.compareTo(a) = 0`.